# Длительная задержка в NGINX ответе сервера - proxy_pass

Tags: php, nginx, proxypass

Есть VPS-сервер, 3 ядра, 4 гигабайта оперативной памяти, Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

На нем установлены NGINX, PHP 8.0-FPM, MYSQL

Весь проект сайта в Laravel 8.0

На виртуальном сервере есть сайт, у которого есть домен + этот сайт используется для Telegram-бота, для использования telegram-бота я сгенерировал самоподписанный сертификат

**Основные данные:
домен - example.com
ip - 196.54.23.2**

Из-за определенных обстоятельств я не могу использовать домен в качестве получателя запросов телеграммы бота, поэтому я использую ip-адрес на порту 443

Проблема в том, что по какой-то причине запросы, которые приходят из телеграмм бота на IP-адрес, обрабатываются в течение 7-10 секунд, то есть, если вы нажмете на что-то в боте, он ответит через 7-10 секунд, а если, например, вы отправите ему 5 команд подряд, он будет поочередно задерживать их выполнение на 7-10 секунд, почему возникает эта задержка, можно ли как-то убрать эту задержку и обработать ее быстрее, в то же время, если я перейду непосредственно к webhook по домену, он загружается быстро, у меня есть подозрения, что это из-за SSL или IPV6, я не знаюне знаю, пожалуйста, скажи мне, Я не силен в настройках сервера (

**в настройках NGINX следующие данные:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen unix:/var/run/nginx.sock;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/project/public;

    charset utf-8;

    if ($host != $server_name) {
        return 403;
    }

    client_body_buffer_size 16k;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    client_body_in_single_buffer off;
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_body_timeout 60s;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
    client_header_timeout 60s;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    index index.php;

    access_log /var/www/project/storage/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/project/storage/logs/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|ico|js|woff2|ttf)$ {
        expires max;
    }
 
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name 196.54.23.2;
    root /var/www/project/public;

    charset utf-8;

    client_body_buffer_size 16k;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    client_body_in_single_buffer off;
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_body_timeout 60s;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
    client_header_timeout 60s;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    index index.php;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    access_log /var/www/project/storage/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/project/storage/logs/nginx_error.log;


    location ~* ^/telegram(.*)+ {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/nginx.sock;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
        proxy_socket_keepalive  on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_temp_path /var/nginx/proxy_temp;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        send_timeout 300;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host "example.com";
        proxy_set_header Host "example.com";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


    location / {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

**UFW STATUS VERBOSE**

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp (Nginx HTTPS)      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp (Apache)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (Nginx HTTPS (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (Apache (v6))       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Возможно, я неправильно установил proxy_pass, скажите мне, в чем может быть проблема, я уже давно не могу ее решить

Comment: Перевел) Я думал тут все по классике на английском нужно писать)

Comment: Конечно, на Stackoverflow __на русском__ надо само собой писать на английском.